# Redirect to home page after timer runs out

Tags: javascript, html

Using javascript, is there a way to implement a timer so that the user only has a limited time to complete a payment form after which a warning is displayed / then the browser redirects to the home page?

Comment: yes possible. Please share your code and show what you have done

Comment: It's pretty simple, but show us what your code looks like

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    var REQIRED_TIME_IN_MS=1000*60*5; //5 minutes
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert("YOUR_MESSEGE");
        window.location.href= "YOUR_HOMEPAGE_LOCATION";
    },REQIRED_TIME_IN_MS);
</script>
```